# Compile time static array of types

Tags: c++

I'm trying to build a static array of dynamic arrays...at compile time.  Some examples:

```
struct Apple {
  int x;
};

struct Pear {
  int a, b;
};
```

then...

```
Registry<Apple, Pear> registry;
auto appleId = registry.add<Apple>(1);
auto pearId = registry.add<Pear>(1, 2);

Apple* apple = registry.get<Apple>(appleId);
```

or...

```
Registry registry;
registry.register<Apple>();
registry.register<Pear>();
```

...although the second example would probably be even harder to do at compile time.

I would assume that the data structure inside looks like this:

```
template <typename... Ts>
struct Registry {
  std::array<std::vector<?>, sizeof...(Ts)> values;
};
```

Any ideas on how to start exploring this problem?

Comment: What does it mean to make something that is dynamic at compile time?

Comment: Sounds to me like you want `std::tuple<std::vector<Apple>, std::vector<Pear>>`, with some convenience functions. Is that right?

Comment: Do you really need a common registry of everything? Why not separate registry<Apple> and registry<Pear>?

Comment: Or maybe you need inheritance here. A superclass `Fruit` from which `Apple` and `Pear` derive.

Comment: Unclear how you want to use it. but it seems you want a `std::tuple`.

Answer (score 4):

`std::vector` can only contain elements of the same type. `std::tuple`, on the other hand, can contain elements of different types:

```
template<typename... Ts>
struct Registry {
    std::tuple<std::vector<Ts>...> values;

    template<class T, class... Args>
    size_t add(Args&&... args) {
        auto& v = std::get<std::vector<T>>(values);
        auto idx = v.size();
        v.emplace_back(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        return idx;
    }

    template<class T>
    T* get(size_t idx) {
        auto& v = std::get<std::vector<T>>(values);
        return idx < v.size() ? &v[idx] : 0;
    }
};

int main() {
    Registry<Apple, Pear> registry;
    auto appleId = registry.add<Apple>(1);
    auto pearId = registry.add<Pear>(1, 2);
    Apple* apple = registry.get<Apple>(appleId);
}
```

However, manipulating such `Registry` in C++17 is run-time only.